# re.split to split using "colon" as separator, and ignore the "colon" if it is among a string of characters enclosed with in \"

Tags: python, regex, parsing, split, expression

re.split to split using "colon" as seperator, and ignore the "colon" if it is among a string of characters enclosed with in \" which is backslash followed by double quotes

here data is Tl1 response.

```
data = "Key1=Value1,key2=Value2:Key3=Value3,key4=\"abc 11:02:65\",key5=Value4:key6=Value6,Value7"
```

i want to write a regular expression that works in python, with which i can split the data on the basis of Colon.Ignoring the ones enclosed in \".

Please help me by giving the correct Regular expression.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please show what you've done, thanks :)

Comment: I was trying out many combinations of reg ex, none worked ..I have no regular expression as the solution for this. I need a solution ..

Comment: See [Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions)

Comment: `text.split(' , ')`

Comment: Are you sure this is the right format? You seem to have a mix of ',' and ':' delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Check if [this reg exp](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5BkK%5Dey.*%3F)%5B%2C%3A%5D(%3F%3D%5BkK%5Dey)%7C(%5BkK%5Dey.*%3F)%24&test_string=Key1%3DValue1%2Ckey2%3DValue2%3AKey3%3DValue3%2Ckey4%3D%5C%22abc%20%2C%2011%3A02%3A65%5C%22%2Ckey5%3DValue4%2Ckey6%3DValue6%2CValue7&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) suits you:

```
([kK]ey.*?)[,:](?=[kK]ey)|([kK]ey.*?)$
```

It will only match `,` or `:` if there are next to a `key` or `Key` value, or if there are the last one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.. You can ignore the whole key value things.. What i need is a regex if i do re.search(exp_here,data) it should select only those colons which are out of \". thats it..

Comment: so, re.split(exp_here,data) will return the following python list:
['"Key1=Value1,key2=Value2',

'Key3=Value3,key4=\"abc 11:02:65\",key5=Value4'

'key6=Value6,Value7']